# Add title and axis labels to riverplot?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, riverplot

I'm trying to make a Sankey diagram using the riverplot package, and was wondering if it's possible to add a title and axis labels to the plot. To keep it simple I'll use one of the sample riverplots from the package:

```
nodes <- c( LETTERS[1:3] )
edges <- list( A= list( C= 10 ), B= list( C= 10 ) )
r <- makeRiver( nodes, edges, node_xpos= c( 1,1,2 ),
                node_labels= c( A= "Node A", B= "Node B", C= "Node C" ),
                node_styles= list( A= list( col= "yellow" )) )
plot( r , srt = 0)
```

[image: riverplot without title/axis labels]

I've tried using labs() and get the following error message: 'non-numeric argument to binary operator' (which wasn't unexpected), but since the package itself doesn't seem to have arguments for the title or axis labels, I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating an empty plot first with your labels and then `riverplot::riverplot` has an argument `add`. Set that to `True` to plot on your empty initial plot. You can customize the initial plot as you see fit with the base facility.

```
# empty plot
plot(0, 
     type = "n",
     xlab = "x-axis", 
     ylab = "y-axis", 
     frame.plot = F,
     xaxt = "n",
     yaxt = "n",
     main = "TITLE")
riverplot::riverplot(r,
                     add = T) # add to empty plot
```

Answer (score 1):

You need function `title`

```r
library(riverplot)


nodes <- c( LETTERS[1:3] )
edges <- list( A= list( C= 10 ), B= list( C= 10 ) )
r <- makeRiver( nodes, edges, node_xpos= c( 1,1,2 ),
                node_labels= c( A= "Node A", B= "Node B", C= "Node C" ),
                node_styles= list( A= list( col= "yellow" )) )

plot(r, srt = 0,
     main = "My Title")

title(main = "My title",
      xlab = "My label for axis X",
      ylab = "My label for axis Y")
```

This code gives you

[image]